# Flexbox background image zoom when hovering

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to create a row of three boxes using flex that remain responsive but have a background image zoom, I've tried a few different ways but it doesn't remain responsive, does anyone know the correct way to do this?

I'm fairly new to flex so please excuse my code, I was also wondering how I can restrict it to 3 per row, as when I add a new `<li>` item it continues to fill the same row.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

h2 {
  color: #3CAD5D;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  max-width: 1500px;
}

li {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
  width: 31.33%;
}

a {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px #888888;
  padding: 20px;
}

a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}


/*** MEDIA QUERIES ***/

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  ul {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  li {
    width: 97%;
  }
}


/*** BG WITH ZOOM ***/

.bg1 {
  background: url('https://cmeimg-a.akamaihd.net/640/clsd/getty/c64f76dc20c246ca88ee180fe4b4b781');
  margin: 5px;
}

.bg2 {
  background: url('http://www.petmd.com/sites/default/files/hypoallergenic-cat-breeds.jpg');
  margin: 5px;
}

.bg3 {
  background: url('https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/images/ic/560x315/p0517py6.jpg');
  margin: 5px;
}

.bg1,
.bg2,
.bg3 {
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s;
  -moz-transition: all .5s;
  -o-transition: all .5s;
  transition: all .5s;
}

.bg1:hover,
.bg2:hover,
.bg3:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.5, 1.5);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="bg1">
    <a href="#">
      <h2>References</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </a>
  </li>

  <li class="bg2">
    <a href="#">
      <h2>References</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </a>
  </li>

  <li class="bg3">
    <a href="#">
      <h2>References</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.Lorem
        ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </a>
  </li>


</ul>
```

Comment: `flex-wrap` defaults to `nowrap`, just change it to wrap and it will wrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (comments in code):

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

h2 {
  color: #3CAD5D;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

ul {
  margin: 0 auto;  /* centre if max-width */
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;  /* add row to this */
  flex-wrap: wrap;     /* allow for extra li */
  max-width: 1500px;
  width:100%;           /* make as wide as possible */
}

li {
  display:flex;                    /* this needs flex so link will fill li */
  width: calc(33.333333% - 10px);  /* fit 3 on a row (10px is your margin) */
}

a {
  flex-grow:1;             /* grow the anchor */
  box-sizing:border-box;   
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px #888888;
  padding: 20px;
}

a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}


/*** MEDIA QUERIES ***/

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  ul {
    flex-direction: column;   /* change direction of flex for mobile */
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  li {
    width: 97%;
  }
}


/*** BG WITH ZOOM ***/

.bg1 {
  background: url('https://cmeimg-a.akamaihd.net/640/clsd/getty/c64f76dc20c246ca88ee180fe4b4b781');
  margin: 5px;
}

.bg2 {
  background: url('http://www.petmd.com/sites/default/files/hypoallergenic-cat-breeds.jpg');
  margin: 5px;
}

.bg3 {
  background: url('https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/images/ic/560x315/p0517py6.jpg');
  margin: 5px;
}

.bg1,
.bg2,
.bg3 {
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s;
  -moz-transition: all .5s;
  -o-transition: all .5s;
  transition: all .5s;
}

.bg1:hover,
.bg2:hover,
.bg3:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.5, 1.5);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="bg1">
    <a href="#">
      <h2>References</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </a>
  </li>

  <li class="bg2">
    <a href="#">
      <h2>References</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </a>
  </li>

  <li class="bg3">
    <a href="#">
      <h2>References</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.Lorem
        ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks! That fixed the issue i'm having with them sticking on the same row, I can't believe I missed that. The next issue is that the images grow huge when I want them to stick to the same size, but zoom in on the background, do you know how I could get that to work?

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you mean by they grow huge?  They grow as much as you zoom them?

Comment: When you hover your mouse over the list items the background image enlarges, but rather than that i'm trying to get it to zoom into the background image, when hovered

Comment: Hmmm, not too sure about that one - perhaps you should ask a new question about that problem as it was not part of your original question

Comment: Thank you for your help, Pete!